# open javafx app when doubleclick on file that's associated with this app

Tags: javafx-8

Is it possible to make a javafx application autoload a specific file when the user opens only this file. Let's say that my application creates files with the extension .em. I know it's possible to make the java app open up when you double-click such a file in Windows explorer, but is it also possible to automatically load this file in into the javafx program? Right now the app is only started, but the data has to be opened from within the app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

I assume you are using Microsoft Windows as your OS. The installers created by the native bundlers are capable of file associations. While developing this extension for the javafx-maven-plugin, I created a [sample-project](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/it/22-create-fileassociations-single-mimetypes/pom.xml#L57), where you can see how to configure this.

example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.zenjava.test.Main</mainClass>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <fileAssociations>
            <fileAssociation>
                <description>association 1</description>
                <extensions>ext1</extensions>
                <contentType>application/dummy</contentType>
                <icon>somePathToIcon</icon>
            </fileAssociation>
            <fileAssociation>
                <description>association 2</description>
                <extensions>ext2</extensions>
                <contentType>application/dummy2</contentType>
            </fileAssociation>
        </fileAssociations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```